# Deleting an item from middle of an array in vba

Tags: arrays, vba, duplicates

Deleting an item from middle of an array in vba

I am looping through two arrays to look for which item in Arr1 is equal to Arr2.
Then I want to delete that item from Arr1. At the end I will add that Arr1 to Arr2.
So, it's somehow detecting if Arr1 has new item that is not in Arr2, and add that item to Arr2

```
Public Sub cmpArr()

For i =LBound(Arr1) To UBound(Arr2)
    For j = LBound(Arr2) To UBound(Arr2)
         If Arr1(i) = Arr2(j) Then
            'Arr1(i) delete
         End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

User braX suggested to use dictionaries. On his advice, I changed using arrays to using dictionaries. Here's code

```
Public Sub comp_2Dictnries()
   For i =0 To dict1.Count -1 
      For j=0 To dict2.Count -1
          On Error Resume Next
          If dict1.Items()(i) =dict2.Items()(j) Then
             dict1.Remove dict1.Keys()(i)
          End If
      Next j
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Does it have to be an array? That's not the best way to create a unique list of items. Have you ever tried a [Scripting Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object)?

Comment: Alternatively, you can look into [ReDim Preserve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/redim-statement) but it's slow and more complicated.

Comment: I remember that the difference in vba between two were it was possible to delete from middle in dictionaries, let me look. If so, I will chnge whole code to it. Arrays were simple to use for me

Comment: Another option would be a [Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/collection-object)

Comment: How to use ReDim Preserve, as I know it is only for dnamic arrays resizing. How can I add functionality to it?

Comment: I recommend the dictionary as you can easily check to see if it's already a member, and when complete, you can easily reference its key array. (so there is your array)

Comment: Yeah, I think remove by key is what I needed in Arrays. I will change my arrays to Dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub replaceArrayElem()
  Dim arr1, arr2, arr3, mtch, i As Long, j As Long
  arr1 = Array("a", "c", "d", "jj", "t", "www")
  arr2 = Array("m", "r", "o", "c", "uu", "n", "d")
  For i = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
        mtch = Application.match(arr2(i), arr1, 0)
        If IsNumeric(mtch) Then 'if a match exists
            arr1(mtch - 1) = "#$@!": arr1 = filter(arr1, "#$@!", False) 'filter eliminate a specific element
        End If
  Next i
  Debug.Print Join(arr1, ",") ' just to visually see how arr1 remained
  arr3 = arr2: ReDim Preserve arr3(UBound(arr2) + UBound(arr1) + 1)
  For i = UBound(arr2) + 1 To UBound(arr3)
       arr3(i) = arr1(j): j = j + 1
  Next i
  Debug.Print Join(arr3, ",") 'the returned array...
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

And a version using a `Scripting.Dictionary` (if you have the arrays, or like working with them):

```
Sub replaceArrayElemDict()
  Dim arr1, arr2, arr3, mtch, i As Long, j As Long
  Dim dict As Object
  
  arr1 = Array("a", "c", "d", "jj", "t", "www")
  arr2 = Array("m", "r", "o", "c", "uu", "n", "d")
  
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  For i = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
        dict(arr2(i)) = vbNullString
  Next i
  For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
        dict(arr1(i)) = vbNullString 'it creates a NEW dictionary key only if it does not exist...
  Next i
  
  Debug.Print Join(dict.Keys, ",") 'the returned array...
End Sub
```

Comment: many topics here, need time to digest . Thanks @FaneDuru

Comment: @xlmaster If something not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications...

Comment: Please, I don't understand `arr1(mtch - 1) = "#$@!"`

Comment: @Waleed It simple replaces the existing (matched) element with a **peculiar string, impossible to be matched inside the other array elements**. ` - 1` because of the fact that match returns starting from 1 and tested array is zero based...  Then using `filter` method with `False` as the third parameter, it returns the array **without that specific element**. Is it clear enough now?